# Any tools to export .NET assembly member's metadata to Excel Sheet

Tags: c#, reflection

Is there a tool that can reflect a .Net Assembly and gets its metadata, viz, Types, Type Members, Access Modifiers details, (Comments?) into an Excel Sheet(s)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for taking time for answering this. However, the following approach met my requirement:

1. Enabled XML documentation for the project
2. Imported the XML documentation into Excel

This not only brought in all types, methods with signature, properties, fields but also all the code comments that i had written for them.

Answer (score 0):

There's not any tool that I know of, but there is an easy way to do this.

Use reflection to inspect an assembly, render this in a HTML table structure, write that to a text file and give that file XLS extension. After that you can open this file in Excel

Hope it helps.